# Group of homomorphisms

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $A$ be a finite, Abelian, additive group. Let $A^{*} = Hom(A, \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$ denote the group of homomorphisms $f$ from $A$ to $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$. Take for granted that $A^{*}$ is an Abelian group (I have already proved this). Prove that $A$ is isomorphic to $A^{*}$ if $A$ is cyclic.

Comment: What's the group operation on $A^*$? $(f \cdot g)(a) = f(a) \cdot g(a)$?

Comment: That is indeed the case!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** If $A$ is cyclic, and $a$ generates it, then every homomorphism $f:A\to G$ is completely determined by $f(a)$.